# how to include original mainifest.mf inside the WAR structure through ANT

Tags: ant, jar, war, build.xml, manifest.mf

I want to create a WAR's and JAR's through ANT process. 
Through Build.xml I am able to create JAR's and WAR's easily but problem lies with the manifest file. 
After searching a lot I found some lines of code which is needed to be added in build.xml to include original manifest.mf file inside the JAR'S but I am stuck when I want my original manifest.mf file inside my WAR. Please help me how to include original mainifest.mf inside the WAR structure through ANT

Comment: What do you mean by "original" manifest? There is a manifest task and both the jar and war tasks have manifest options. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `filesetmanifest="merge"` to solved the problem.